# What does it mean to be "in suspense"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, nouns

What does it actually mean to be "in suspense"?  It's not a place, or a verb.  How would you define "suspense"?

Comment: "In suspense" literally means being suspended or hung, as if by wires.  The term is used figuratively to mean that a person's emotions are "hanging" as if frozen in midair, waiting for some situation to be resolved.

Answer (score 10):

*[Suspense](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspense)* (the correct spelling) is an emotional state. Just as one can be *in fear*, one can be *in suspense*.

Comment: Very nice desciprtion of being in suspense, @Phenry

Comment: @Phenry thanks, are emotional states official gramatical terms?.

Comment: @wizlog - no, but that isn't really important when you're deciding what preposition to use, or how to apply the word. (Grammatically, *suspense* is a noun.)

Comment: +1. You can also be *in love*, *in awe*, *in contemplation*...

Comment: Are you sure contemplation is a emotional state?

Comment: And to answer the original question, being in suspense means being in a state of suspense (i.e. a state of tension with unresolved issues and an uncertain outcome).

Comment: @wizlog I would say so.  The first definition of contemplation is the action, but the second is "deep reflective thought", and I would say that's an emotional state. (Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 3):

I think understanding the origin of the word is helpful in *picturing* its meaning in this case.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=suspense&searchmode=none) relates it (through its French origin) to [*suspend*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suspend). If you imagine a person in *suspense* to be *suspended* in the *defer or delay* sense, or metaphorically hung up in the *hang* sense, in their desire for knowledge, you can get a good feel of the mental state *suspense* is describing.

Further, [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suspense) states the French origin as *suspens* 'abeyance'. *Abeyance* simply means [a state of temporary disuse](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abeyance), which has similar connotations.

You can also think of suspense being related to curiosity. When you are intensely curious about something but the situation has temporarily suspended satiation of that curiosity, you experience suspense.

Answer (score -2):

SUSPENSE: anxious uncertainty about the outcome of events in a literary work.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @T'Ajena. Your post would be improved if it included a reference. I suspect the down votes are because you take a very narrow view of the word in question.